# enums to be defined as uint8_t variables in structure

Tags: c++, c, qt-creator

I have an enum in a structure:

```c
enum Days : uint8_t
{
  day1 =1,
  day2 =2,
  day2 =3
}

struct Hi
{
  Days days;
}
```

On compilation, I get an error `Scoped enums not available in this version`.
I need all my enums to be an `uint8_t` type and defined in the structure.

Comment: You need C++11 support. What compiler do you use?

Comment: Why? Do you have a requirement that this code not compile for platforms that do not have an exact 8-bit unsigned integer type? Such a requirement would be very rare. `uint_least8_t` or `uint_fast8_t` is almost certainly better. So is `unsigned char`, which is required to b at least 8 bits wide and unsigned.

Comment: I need to have enums strictly 8 bits .

Comment: What is it, C or C++? Their concepts of enumerations are quite different.

Comment: day2 is repeated two times!

Answer (score 5):

Even prior to C++11, if you take care that all of your enum values are less than 128, you can simply store them in a uint8_t variable.  This may require casting when they're used, though.  This is a common way to squeeze enum values into a structure, especially in embedded code where memory is tight.  This technique also improves your data cache hit ratio if your code uses a lot of instances of these structures.

```
enum Days
{
    Day1 =1,
    Day2 =2,
    Day3 =3
};
typedef uint8_t DaysTy;

// Totally optional, but allows you to send a 'DaysTy' to cout directly:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const DaysTy& d)
{
    const char* txt="ILLEGAL";
    switch (d)
    {
        case Day1: txt = "Day1"; break;
        case Day2: txt = "Day2"; break;
        case Day3: txt = "Day3"; break;
    }
    s << txt;
    return s;
}

struct Hi
{
    DaysTy dayA;
    DaysTy dayB;
    DaysTy dayC;

    // Totally optional, but allows you to send a 'Hi' struct to cout directly:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Hi& m);
};

// Totally optional, but allows you to send a 'Hi' struct to cout directly:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Hi& h)
{
    s << '[' << h.dayA << ',' << h.dayB << ',' << h.dayC << ']';
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    Hi aHiObject;
    aHiObject.dayA = Day3;
    aHiObject.dayB = Day2;
    aHiObject.dayC = Day1;

    std::cout << "my Hi object: " << aHiObject << '\n';
    if (aHiObject.dayA == Day1)
        std::cout << "Its dayA is Day1.\n";
    if (aHiObject.dayA == Day2)
        std::cout << "Its dayA is Day2.\n";
    if (aHiObject.dayA == Day3)
        std::cout << "Its dayA is Day3.\n";

    std::cout << "sizeof(aHiObject)      = " << sizeof(aHiObject) << " byte(s)\n"
                 "sizeof(aHiObject.dayA) = " << sizeof(aHiObject.dayA) << " byte(s)\n";

    std::cout << "Value '3' as a uint8_t: " << (uint8_t)3 << '\n';
    std::cout << "Value '3' as a DaysTy: "  << (DaysTy)3  << '\n';

    std::cout << "Value '4' as a uint8_t: " << (uint8_t)4 << '\n';
    std::cout << "Value '4' as a DaysTy: "  << (DaysTy)4  << '\n';
}
```

Running this code produces this output:

```
my Hi object: [Day3,Day2,Day1]
Its dayA is Day3.
sizeof(aHiObject)      = 3 byte(s)
sizeof(aHiObject.dayA) = 1 byte(s)
Value '3' as a uint8_t: Day3
Value '3' as a DaysTy: Day3
Value '4' as a uint8_t: ILLEGAL
Value '4' as a DaysTy: ILLEGAL
```

...which incidentally shows that Mike Seymour's comment below is correct.  Nevertheless, this demonstrates a way you can pack your enum values into uint8_t variable types.

Comment: I am using C++03 and I strictly needs all the enums to be uint8_t as I need to interface with embedded system

Comment: @user2618994 - So get rid of the `: uint8_t` after `enum Days`, and perhaps add a `typedef uint8_t DaysTy`, and every time you need to create an instance of a `Day`, just define the variable as type `DaysTy`.  E.g.:   `DaysTy today = day1`.  (I'd recommend redefining your enum with all-caps `DAY1 = 1`, etc, or perhaps `Day1 = 1`, etc.)  When you use such a variable, you may find in some circumstances that you'll need to cast it as `Days` to avoid compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: @user2618994 - What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user2618994: That compiler should be fine, even though it's a few years old. Are you enabling C++11 support with `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: I need to have the enums as uint8_t in my structure strictly as i am dealing with hardware system. –

Comment: You can't declare that overload of `operator<<` since `DaysTy` is an alias for a built-in arithmetic types, and overloads already exist for all of them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - Thank you for that observation.  My answer now shows this.  As this is an ancillary issue to the post, I'm not bothering to adjust my posted answer, but I am showing what you commented about.

Answer (score 4):

If you're writing C++, and you can update to a modern compiler (or possibly enable C++11 support in your compiler) then your code is fine.

If you're writing C or historic C++, then you can't - these languages simply don't allow you to specify the size of an enumeration. You'll have to use `uint8_t` where you need an explicit size, and convert when necessary:

```
struct Hi {
    uint8_t days;
};

Hi hi;

hi.days = static_cast<uint8_t>(day1);
Days d = static_cast<Days>(hi.days);
```

Comment: I need to have the enums as uint8_t in my structure strictly as i am dealing with hardware system.

Comment: @user2618994: Then have a `uint8_t` in your structure for hardware compatibility, and convert to and from the enumeration when accessing it. Or fix your compiler.

Comment: i had defined uint8_t days  in my structure, but it shows an error,

Comment: @user2618994: Probably because you're not using explicit conversions between the enumeration and integer types. See my updated answer.

Comment: THe code looks good. BUt how to cast all the enums to uin8_t and have a object tied to the enum which is uin8_t

Comment: @user2618994: I don't know what you mean by "an object tied to the enum". You'll need to use `uint8_t` when you need a particular size, `Days` where you want the convenience of the enumeration, and conversions where necessary. Or update your compiler.